# Updating a global variable / resource in Reducers via a socket to the Hadoop job tracker

Tags: sockets, hadoop

I need a global variable that can be read / set simultaneously in reducers (I am aware of the bottleneck and performance issues of such design). I tried to use Hadoop Configuration get()/set(), but I found that configuration properties need to be set before submitting the mapreduce job, and that using Configuration.set() within a reducer doesn't actually update the global property's value.

Closest thing I could find is to use a global parameter than can be read/set via a socket to the Hadoop job tracker, but I failed to find any resources illustrating how this can be done.

My question is:

1. How to read/set a global variable via a socket to the Hadoop job
   tracker.
2. Is there are another way to keeping a global variable
   (regardless of performance degradation)

Notes:

- Hadoop counters cannot work for me since they don't support a set() function
- DistributedCache won't work since it is used for distributing read-only data, while in my case I need reducers to update the value of a global variable that can be read simultaneously by other running reduce tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the place to store reliably-consistent global variables in a Hadoop cluster is [Apache ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/).

That said, it is rare to require mutable global variables in a MapReduce job. If you share your use case there is a good chance there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy for your reply. My case is that I am using a distributed branch and bound algorithm during the reduction phase. So, i need a "bestSoFar" variable to keep the best answer found till now. This value is used to stop many reducers from executing if the upper bound for a subproblem at one reducer is less than the "bestSoFar" value. In general, I am trying to implement this paper about a distributed max clique algorithm using MapReduce: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~ashraf/pubs/icde13maxclique.pdf